# Can you damage a voltmeter using this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries

If I hand a small child two batteries and noodle-sized LCD voltmeter, can they damage the voltmeter by using this circuit?

I am positive it's completely safe, but I have to ask.

Batteries may be different voltages or the same voltage.

[image]

Comment: not with this circuit. but they could put the batteries in series and connect them through the low impedance current input effectively short-circuiting them. This can lead to lots of heat (in the batteries).

Comment: Yes indeed! I was thinking of only using those three elements. They idea is that the children would be demonstrated a small red hot wire/a spark using a short circuit, and wouldn't have metal to short circuit it themselves unless supervised!

Comment: @tobalt That assumes there is a current input. With the AliExpress voltmeter shown, the only way to damage it is to reverse the polarity and possible burn out the voltmeter.

Comment: *If I hand a small child*.  Hopefully they lose interest in your social experiment before they get hurt.  3 objects and 2 hands.  I'd say you are very optimistic!

Comment: They might eat or chew on stuff and that won't be good. Are you related to Ivan Pavlov?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, YOUR SOCIAL EXPERIMENT... your brain is a social fantasy land apparently. I rewrote the question to de-fog your presumptions. At least you gave context for the reason of you downvote, most people don't have the balls. I own rats by the way. theyre fun.

Comment: ROFL I didn't down vote. You expect much from a child with three objects.

Comment: "I am positive it's completely safe, but I have to ask." So what is the real reason you asked?

Comment: Because I don't do counter intuitive and silly things with electricity like that displayed in the image, so I have never considered what the physical properties of that kind of circuit can be? Having imagined it from a child's perspective, I had to ask because I didn't know that voltage would run from the highest voltage battery through the other one.

Comment: Doesn't it say on batteries, "Keep away from children"? Small children frequently EAT batteries.

Comment: Lol!!! like give it to a dude in nappies! no way i didn't consider that. not toddlers. that's different. 14 is still little! I was thinking 12+? I think my physics course involving D cells unsupervised was when i was 12.

Comment: I have no trouble with asking the question, and didn't downvotr, but I'm pretty curious about the learning objectives

Comment: If batteries are small enough to swallow and are swallowed that can cause death or extremely severe life changing injuries. Sadly, this really happens. This is usually not a risk with D cells :-).It is an extremely real risk with "coin cells" :-( is The damage is caused by a conduction oath between battery terminals forming due to the conductive environment. Severe lesions can easily firm and if the gut or throat wall is penetrated (as really happens) death can occur. Prompt surgery is required, and in your target context may be relatively unavailable.

Comment: Specifying age range in the question will help. || I'm a moderator. I suggest that a neutral reaction to seemingly snarky questions is liable to get better results. People can have genuine concerns expressed poorly. || Most AliExpress noodle voltmeters allow negative polarity. This is easily tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those two batteries are of the same voltage and are connected back to back as in the diagram, the voltage at the voltmeter would be zero, and it should not damage any voltmeter. If the two batteries are of different voltages VL (left) and VR (right), the effective voltage at the voltmeter would be the difference of voltages Ve = VR - VL (assuming red wire goes to the positive terminal.  If Ve is higher than the max voltage that can be applied to the voltmeter, or if Ve is negative and the voltmeter is not tolerant to wrong polarity, the voltmeter could be damaged.

Comment: Thanks, awesome information.